# How to remove unwanted vertical spacing(centering) on tables that are side by side

Tags: tables, xetex

Hey I have 5 tables that I want to be laid out in a certain way.  I can't really think of a way to ask this question but the issue is **each table vertically centers itself to the bigger table**. How do I stop this, let alone control vertical spacing on tables before and after it?  Any help is much appreciated.

Expectation:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[letterpaper, inner=16mm, outer=16mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!15} 
                                        
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{2.3in}
                \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}XX}
                \rowcolor{black}
                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont Header } \\
                \rowcolor{black!60}
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\         
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\noindent\begin{minipage}{2.3in}
  
                \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}XX}
                \rowcolor{black}
                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont Header } \\
                \rowcolor{black!60}
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\         
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\noindent\begin{minipage}{2.3in}
                \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}XX}
                \rowcolor{black}
                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont Header } \\
                \rowcolor{black!60}
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\         
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\             
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\noindent\begin{minipage}{2.3in}
                \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}XX}
                \rowcolor{black}
                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont Header } \\
                \rowcolor{black!60}
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\         
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\noindent\begin{minipage}{2.3in}
                \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}XX}
                \rowcolor{black}
                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont Header } \\
                \rowcolor{black!60}
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\         
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \end{tabularx}
                \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a combination of three top ailgned minipages with two or one tabularx and `\raisebox` in order to top align the `tabularx` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[letterpaper, inner=16mm, outer=16mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!15} 
                                        
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{2.3in}
\raisebox{-\height}{
                \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}XX}
                \rowcolor{black}
                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont Header } \\
                \rowcolor{black!60}
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\         
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \end{tabularx}}
                    \medskip
                    
                \raisebox{-\height}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}XX}
                \rowcolor{black}
                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont Header } \\
                \rowcolor{black!60}
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\         
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 

                    \end{tabularx}}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.3in}
  
                \raisebox{-\height}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}XX}
                \rowcolor{black}
                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont Header } \\
                \rowcolor{black!60}
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\         
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\

                    \end{tabularx}}
                    \medskip
                    
               \raisebox{-\height}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}XX}
                \rowcolor{black}
                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont Header } \\
                \rowcolor{black!60}
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\         
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\
                    \end{tabularx}}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.3in}
                \raisebox{-\height}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}XX}
                \rowcolor{black}
                    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\centering\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont Header } \\
                \rowcolor{black!60}
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black!60}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\         
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\             
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  & 
                    \color{black}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont  \\ 
                    \end{tabularx}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was researching the [t] but I didn't know you could use it in minipage.  Very good job friend, am eternally grateful.